# React native ScrollView onScroll event

Tags: react-native, scrollview

How I can call both function from onScroll?
I trying this

```
onScroll={
        (event) => console.log(event),
        Animated.event(
          [
            { nativeEvent:
              {
                contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY },
              },
            },
          ])
      }
```

but it's not work together, only separate. For example, If I comment ether console.log or Animated.event there are working.

Answer (score 1):

ops, got it

```
 onScroll={
            Animated.event(
              [
                { nativeEvent:
                  {
                    contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY },
                  },
                },
              ],
              { listener: (event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y) }
            )
          }
```